# Where can I find a schedule of small rodeos in Arizona and Utah?

Tags: events, utah, arizona, colorado, new-mexico

We're making a driving trip through Arizona and Utah (and a bit of New Mexico and Colorado), and we would like to see a rodeo along the way. I'm hoping there's a central list of rodeos online so I can schedule a stop somewhere instead of relying on chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many resources you can look at.  You can probably start with official tourist guides for the states such as [Arizona Guide](http://www.arizonaguide.com/experience-and-share/featured-article/celebrate-cowboy-style-at-arizonas-winter-rodeos-old-west-events) or [Utah.com](http://www.utah.com), but if not you can probably [Google IT](https://www.google.com/search?q=Arizona+Rodeo+schedule&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us%3aIE-Address&ie=&oe=#q=Rodeo+schedule&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us%3aIE-Address) or use [Rodeoz](http://www.rodeoz.com), which has some of the many rodeos listed state by state.